# Filter list of dictionaries contains same key, value

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
l = [
  {'a': 123, 'b': 456},
  {'a': 322, 'b': 44454},
  {'a': 123, 'b': 134}
]
```

I want to filter list based upon key `a` of each dictionary. If key, value   `'a': 123` exist in any other dictionary of list then remove any one of these two and I want filtered result like:

```
[
  {'a': 123, 'b': 456}, 
  {'a': 3222, 'b': 44454}
]
# 1st and 3rd dict have same 'a': 123 so remove 3rd dictionary, don't care about value of 'b'.

# or

[
  {'a': 3222, 'b': 44454}, 
  {'a': 123, 'b': 134}
]
# 1st and 3rd dict have same 'a': 123 so remove 1st dictionary. Don't care about value of 'b'.
```

I have tried different ways but all are successful in case if list of dictionaries have all keys and values same.

```
import itertools, operator, pprint
from operator import itemgetter

l = [
  {'a': 123, 'b': 456},
  {'a': 322, 'b': 44454},
  {'a': 123, 'b': 134}
]

getvals = operator.itemgetter('a', 'b')
l.sort(key=getvals)
result = []

for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, getvals):
    result.append(g.next())

l[:] = result
pprint.pprint(l)
```

But result is

```
[{'a': 123, 'b': 134}, {'a': 123, 'b': 456}, {'a': 322, 'b': 44454}]
```

How I can filter my list ?

Comment: Do you want to filter only based on key 'a', on keys 'a' and 'b' or based on all keyys in all dictionaries

Comment: only on base key 'a'

Comment: `getvals = operator.itemgetter('a', 'b')` doesn't look right to me if you're only interested in a and not b.

Comment: oh my bad, it should be `getvals = operator.itemgetter('a')`.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason of negative vote??

Comment: `list(map(itemgetter(0), (list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter('a')), key=itemgetter('a')))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it is this:

```
l = [{'a': 123, 'b': 456}, {'a': 322, 'b': 44454}, {'a': 123, 'b': 134}]

newList = []

#Get all unique values of key 'a'.
values = list(set(i['a'] for i in l))

# Filter the dictionary.
for i in l:
    for v in values:
        if i['a']==v:
            newList.append(i)
            values.remove(v)
            break

#Print result.
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 123, 'b': 456}, {'a': 322, 'b': 44454}]
```

Comment: perfect! what I need!  but don't know Why people negative vote without any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
values = []
new_x = []
for d in l:
    if not d['a'] in values:
        new_x.append(d)
        values.append(d['a'])

print(new_x)
```

Comment: your solution also worked for me but @Vasilis G. solution best for my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple *seen* list to store your values as you iterate over them and then export to the new list only the dictionaries whose values you haven't seen before, e.g.

```
def filter_dicts(target, key):
    seen = set()  # a temporary set to store already visited values
    return [d for d in target if d[key] not in seen and not seen.add(d[key])]
```

You can test it with:

```
l = [
    {'a': 123, 'b': 456},
    {'a': 322, 'b': 44454},
    {'a': 123, 'b': 134}
]
k = filter_dicts(l, "a")
#   [
#     {'a': 123, 'b': 456},
#     {'a': 322, 'b': 44454}
#   ]
```

The order doesn't have to match as `dict` is, generally, an unordered structure.

Comment: your solution also worked for me but @Vasilis G. solution best for my case.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool - Far be it for me to impose, but his solution is incredibly inefficient.